# How to extract file names from a field that contains html content in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

We have a cms system that write html content blocks into sql server database.
I know the table name and field name where these html content blocks reside.
Some html contains links () to pdf files. Here is a fragment:

```
<p>A deferred tuition payment plan, 
or view the <a href="/uploadedFiles/Tuition-Reimbursement-Deferred.pdf"
target="_blank">list</a>.</p>
```

I need to extract pdf file names from all such html content blocks.
At the end I need to get a list:

```
Tuition-Reimbursement-Deferred.pdf
Some-other-file.pdf
```

of all pdf file names from that field.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have received many replies, thank you so much, 
but I forgot to mention that we are still using SQL Server 2000 here.
So, this had to be done using SQL 2000 SQL.

Comment: Will they all have a folder that precedes the filename?

Comment: Do you have to do this in TSQL? It's a very poor language for text parsing, and it would be much easier in a different language that has an HTML parsing library.

Comment: Agree, that's just a quick options. If needed I will use HTMLAgilityPack in my C# code to parse the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not pretty but this works using standard Transact-SQL:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.pdf', html) > 0
            THEN SUBSTRING(
                     html,
                     CHARINDEX('.pdf', html) -
                     PATINDEX(
                         '%["/]%',
                         REVERSE(SUBSTRING(html, 0, CHARINDEX('.pdf', html)))) + 1,
                     PATINDEX(
                         '%["/]%',
                         REVERSE(SUBSTRING(html, 0, CHARINDEX('.pdf', html)))) + 3)
            ELSE NULL
       END AS filename
FROM mytable
```

Could expand the list of delimiting characters before the filename from `["/]` (which matches *either* a quotation mark or slash) if you like.

See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/92764/6)

Comment: Great, I forgot to mention that we have SQL 2000 here, so this approach works !! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

**Create this function**:

```
create function dbo.extract_filenames_from_a_tags (@s nvarchar(max))
returns @res table (pdf nvarchar(max)) as
begin
-- assumes there are no single quotes or double quotes in the PDF filename
declare @i int, @j int, @k int, @tmp nvarchar(max);
set @i = charindex(N'.pdf', @s);
while @i > 0
begin
  select @tmp = left(@s, @i+3);
  select @j = charindex('/', reverse(@tmp)); -- directory delimiter
  select @k = charindex('"', reverse(@tmp)); -- start of href
  if @j = 0 or (@k > 0 and @k < @j) set @j = @k;
  select @k = charindex('''', reverse(@tmp)); -- start of href (single-quote*)
  if @j = 0 or (@k > 0 and @k < @j) set @j = @k;
  insert @res values (substring(@tmp, len(@tmp)-@j+2, len(@tmp)));
  select @s = stuff(@s, 1, @i+4, ''); -- remove up to ".pdf"
  set @i = charindex(N'.pdf', @s);
end
return
end
GO
```

**A demo on using that function**:

```
declare @t table (html varchar(max));
insert @t values
  ('
<p>A deferred tuition payment plan, 
or view the <a href="/uploadedFiles/Tuition-Reimbursement-Deferred.pdf"
target="_blank">list</a>.</p>'),
  ('
<p>A deferred tuition payment plan, 
or view the <a href="Two files here-Reimbursement-Deferred.pdf"
target="_blank">list</a>.</p>And I use single quotes
   <a href=''/look/path/The second file.pdf''
target="_blank">list</a>');

select t.*, p.pdf
from @t t
cross apply dbo.extract_filenames_from_a_tags(html) p;
```

**Results**:

```
|HTML                  |                                       PDF |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|<p>A deferred tui.... |        Tuition-Reimbursement-Deferred.pdf |
|<p>A deferred tui.... | Two files here-Reimbursement-Deferred.pdf |
|<p>A deferred tui.... |                       The second file.pdf |
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0039c/1/0)

Comment: That is an awesome function.

Comment: Great thanks a lot, it works perfect, but I forgot to mention that we still using SQL Server 2000 here, and this code wont work on SQL 2000.

Answer (score 1):

How about treating that HTML as XML?

```
declare @t table (html varchar(max));
insert @t 
    select '
    <p>A deferred tuition payment plan, 
    or view the <a href="/uploadedFiles/Tuition-Reimbursement-Deferred.pdf"
    target="_blank">list</a>.</p>'
    union all
    select '
    <p>A deferred tuition payment plan, 
    or view the <a href="Two files here-Reimbursement-Deferred.pdf"
    target="_blank">list</a>.</p>And I use single quotes
       <a href=''/look/path/The second file.pdf''
    target="_blank">list</a>'

select  [filename] = reverse(left(reverse('/'+p.n.value('@href', 'varchar(100)')), charindex('/',reverse('/'+p.n.value('@href', 'varchar(100)')), 1) - 1))
from    (   select  cast(html as xml)
            from    @t
        ) x(doc)
cross
apply doc.nodes('//a') p(n);
```

Results:

```
filename
---------------------------------------------------------------
Tuition-Reimbursement-Deferred.pdf
Two files here-Reimbursement-Deferred.pdf
The second file.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 
'<p>A deferred tuition payment plan, 
or view the <a href="/uploadedFiles/Tuition-Reimbursement-Deferred.pdf"
target="_blank">list</a>.</p>'

SELECT 
      ref_text = t.p.value('./a[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
    , ref_filename = REVERSE(
                        LEFT(REVERSE(t.p.value('./a[1]/@href', 'NVARCHAR(50)')), 
                        CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(t.p.value('./a[1]/@href', 'NVARCHAR(50)')), 1) - 1))
FROM @XML.nodes('/p') t(p)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I forgot to mention that we are still using SQL Server 2000 here, and it doesnt have XML data type :(